# Cannot install llvmpy "can't open file 'llvmpy/build.py'"

Tags: python, llvm, llvm-py

I have some trouble installing `llvmpy` on ubuntu 14.04, i downloaded llvmpy from llvmpy.org and installed `llvm 3.4` via `apt-get`, when I try to install it using

```
python setup.py install
```

I get this error:

```
Error: could not invoke ['llvm-config', '--version']
Try setting LLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/llvm-config
```

Then i used

```
LLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/bin/llvm-config python setup.py install
```

and i got

```
LLVM version = u'3.4'
LLVM targets = 
Generate intrinsic IDs
Searching shared library libLLVM-3.4 in /usr/lib/llvm-3.4/lib
Using dynamic linking
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'llvmpy/build.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 142, in <module>
    check_call([sys.executable, 'llvmpy/build.py'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', 
'llvmpy/build.py']'    returned non-zero exit status 2
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you got it from the tar.gz file available at https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/llvmpy/llvmpy-0.12.4.tar.gz , it is incomplete, try download as a zip from github https://github.com/llvmpy/llvmpy

Or directly via git commands